# Grafana false positive SNMP down

Tags: docker, nagios, snmp, grafana

**NOTE:** I also have Nagios running on another server that reports bandwidth warnings and up/down status. Not a single switch is alerting from this, only Grafana.

Grafana version `1.14.1`

I was receiving alerts every minute of all switches reporting as down.

[image: grafana_false_positive]

The metrics portion of the dashboard is:

`up{instance="192.168.20.20",job="snmp"}` <--- same for all 12 switches that are polled

I was able to log in to the switch during these reported "outages." No other services were showing interruption (e.g. servers connected to those switches). I have yet to see something like this, and I'm trying to figure out how I can troubleshoot. If there is not actually a problem, what would cause this false positive?

Grafana runs in a Docker container, and I cannot seem to find anything in `/var/log/grafana/grafana.log.*` related to switches.

Any ideas on where I could glean some info to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Grafana is just a visualization tool. And as you can see, It is doing that job very well.

Two things :

1. It can be your data source's problem. Check if there's actual data is.
2. If you are crawling metrics by using script/daemon, then check that too.

Comment: It's not doing its job very well if the switch is up, but it's reporting down. I have no scripts crawling metrics.